# How to unit test a call-back function? (C++ Boost Unit test)

Tags: unit-testing, boost

I want to unit test a client/server function. The client calls the server, the server calls a callback function. Something like:

```
void CallBack()
{
    BOOST_SUCCESS(); // test is successful if this is called
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ConnectionTest_ClientCallback )
{
    CallServer(); // server will do work and call CallBack()
    sleep(20);
    BOOST_FAIL("Server hasn't called CallBack() within specified time limit.");
}
```

But the above won't work because CallBack() could be called during any of the tests. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In the callback function set a variable:

```
void CallBack()
{
    callBackCalled = true;
}
```

And test that in the test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ConnectionTest_ClientCallback )
{
    callbackCalled = false;
    CallServer(); // server will do work and call CallBack()
    sleep(20);
    if (callbackCalled)
        BOOST_SUCCESS();
    else
        BOOST_FAIL("Server hasn't called CallBack() within specified time limit.");
}
```

Edit: Better solution suggested by kizzx2:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ConnectionTest_ClientCallback )
{
    callbackCalled = false;
    CallServer(); // server will do work and call CallBack()
    sleep(20);
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(callbackCalled, "Server hasn't called CallBack() within specified time limit.");
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to say `BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(callbackCalled, "Server hasn't called CallBack() within specified time limit.")` instead of 4 lines?

Comment: @kizzx2: I wasn't aware of that - I'll amend my answer.